# Running objdump under docker shows different result

Tags: c, docker, gcc, gdb, objdump

Assume this `c` code:

```
int main(){
 return 0;
}
```

Compiled using `gcc` under a normal running linux machine, and running `objdump -d` on the output shows the following:

```
00000000004004cd <main>:
  4004cd:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004ce:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4004d1:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
...
```

I can easily set `breakpoints` in gdb using the `0x4004cd` address.

Doing the same in a Docker container has weird memory addresses on the left (`5fa`) side and I can't breakpoint on them. Why is this happening?

```
00000000000005fa <main>:
 5fa:   55                      push   %rbp
 5fb:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 5fe:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

The compiler in your Docker container is configured to build [position-independent executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) by default.

You can verify this by running `file a.out`, which should show `ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable` in docker, and `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64` outside of it.

You can disable building PIE with: `gcc -no-pie -fno-pie ...`.

> I can't breakpoint on them

You can't breakpoint on instruction at `0x5fa` because that's not the address at which the binary actually runs. Instead, do this:

```
(gdb) start
(gdb) disas main
```

Above command will show you where the binary was relocated at runtime, and you should now be able to set breakpoints on relocated addresses.

Comment: Thanks alot, so in this case, what is `5fa`? is it an offset form the start location?

Comment: @Josh `0x5fa` is the *relative* address of code. It's relative to the address where the binary will actually be loaded, and that address is only known at runtime.

Comment: so then an offset from where it will be loaded?

Comment: @Josh Isn't that what I said? "offset from x" and "address relative to x" are synonyms.